# How to make a job in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, updates, jobs

I need a help.
This is my job:

```
begin
    dbms_scheduler.create_job(
    job_name    =>  'test_job21',
    job_type    =>  'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action  =>  'job_test',
    start_date  =>  to_timestamp_tz('2018-04-18 18:09:00', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr'),
    auto_drop   =>  FALSE,
    enabled     =>  TRUE
    );

    dbms_scheduler.run_job('test_job21', use_current_session => false);
end;
```

But, this condition start_date not is respected, after that job is saved this trigger in my job is executed.
How i could resolve that?

Comment: Not sure what time zone is tzr, but can it be possible the start_date was already in the past when you submitted it?

Comment: Thanks for code organization.
So, that time zone it was wrong, really.
But, the start_date dont was in past...=/
And i tried again and this job, it is in the same problem

Comment: So...
The wrong was the line that contains ' dbms_scheduler.run_job' that executing my job immediatelly

Answer (score 1):

I have never worked myself with dbms_scheduler, but you could try this:

Simply let the scheduler do its job and leave out the `run_job()` command.

In the package spec of `dbms_scheduler` it says that `run_job()` will run a job *immediately*.